# wpf usercontrol: append content

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

If I have a UserControl that has content in it already, how do I add content to a certain portion of the user control. See below. I tried this but it doesn't show anything.

```
<!--user control xaml-->
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <TextBlock/>
    <ContentControl Grid.Row="1" Margin="10" Name="MyContent" >

    </ContentControl>
</Grid>

<!--usercontrol declared somewhere-->
<views:MyControl Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" >
    <views:MyControl.MyContent>
        <Grid/>
    </views:MyControl.MyContent>
</views:MyControl >
```

Comment: `add content to a certain portion` you mean update UI or add new UI controls to your `UserContorl`?

Comment: I want to be able to add any control to MyContent.

Comment: This is a fairly decent tutorial on the different way to accomplish this. http://www.ikriv.com/dev/wpf/displayingcontent/index.html .